# Can I carry DIY electronics to a plane?

Tags: airport-security

I am an electronics engineer and electronics enthusiast with the desire to monitor different parameters at different times.

I've created a small X-Y-Z planes accelerometer, which I would like to take to the airplane to measure accelerations during takeoff and landing.

May I have any kind of problems carrying this item on the plane, for which I will add a switch and a 9V battery?

What are actual regulations about DIY electronics? I know you can carry a laptop, tablet, phone, camera, etc., but DIY?

PS: Would it make easier to carry if I'd put it into a 3D-printed case?

PS2: I forgot to mention it, I'm flying inside the EU with Ryanair and Easyjet.

[image]

Comment: flying inside Europe

Comment: I flew with DIY kits from china to EU. They didn't ask any question but they were very strict with batteries.  It would be good if you keep the label from kit manufacturer which describes the kit.

Answer (score 7):

There aren't any regulations I know of specifically covering bringing DIY electronics (it would be a weird thing to make a regulation about). I've carried them many times, and only had something inspected once: They swabbed it with an explosive detection swab, waited for the beep, and let me go on my way.

Actually *using* such a thing on a plane may be different. I'm gonna go waaaay out on a limb and guess that you haven't subjected that thing to EMF testing.

Comment: Nope, didn't. But still, since it doesn't have a transmitter/receiver, why would it be under question?

Comment: Every electronic circuit with active components is a transmitter. The question is, is it the sort of transmitter that could interfere with the plane's communication or navigation systems.

Comment: It is not disturbing plane's communication whatsoever. But I cannot negotiate that with security, right?
My real question here is, whether they are gonna think I'm a terrorist and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Nope, they won't. Once they've swabbed it (if they even do that), there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: I suggest reading [UNDERSTANDING THE FCC REGULATIONS FOR COMPUTERS AND OTHER DIGITAL DEVICES](https://transition.fcc.gov/Bureaus/Engineering_Technology/Documents/bulletins/oet62/oet62rev.pdf). In its terms, most of the devices airlines have approved for use in flight are Class B devices. The development process for computers includes testing according to the Class A or Class B standards.

Comment: @Jakey: Unless you have tested the device for RF noise you _don't know_ whether it will interfere with the plane's systems if you power it up. And even if _you_ have tested it, the crew _still won't know_ that, as long as the test hasn't been signed off by a qualified laboratory.

Comment: @HenningMakholm TL;DR you can't take custom electronics to a plane?
PS: What about if I'd made my own phone and disguise it in a case of Nokia 3310? They probably wouldn't check it, tho.

Comment: @Jakey: I would be surprised if you're allowed to _use_ custom electronics on the plane. If you get things aboard the plane by fraud like you describe, you'd probably be risking at criminal charges for knowingly jeopardizing safety, rather than just getting told to power it down.

Answer (score 2):

You will definitely not be allowed to use your custom device on your Easyjet flight. They list [what can be used](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/archive/on-your-flight/electronic-devices), and specifically say that devices without a "Flight Safe" mode must be switched off.